# Execute Python Script from google spreadsheet

Tags: python, google-sheets

Is it possible to run a python script from GoogleSheets(GS)?
The idea is that I press a button in GS and the python script runs.
I found some older posts about this, like the idea to run it from Google Cloud, but maybe there is a simpler solution in the meantime?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Python script will have to be run from the cloud. See [URL Fetch Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch).